# Is there a way to add class name to fields of a Model formset or a inline formset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
ItemImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Item, ItemImage, extra=5, max_num=5)
image_formset = ItemImageFormSet()
```

I use the above code to create an **inline formset** of images relating to an item. I need a way to add **class name** to the resultant html to decorate the presentation. For regular forms, I usually add class name in their respective `__init__()`, but that approach is not feasible for formsets. Is  there a way to achieve my ask?

Comment: If you do it in a single form, perhaps you can apply your pattern iterating over all forms in formset: `for form in image_formset: form.my_class = 'Item'` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inlineformset_factory accepts a form argument, you can create your custom modelform and than send it to the factory

```
ItemImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Item, ItemImage, form=ItemImage, extra=5, max_num=5)
```